# Webpack + Keycloak JavaScript: Resource was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”)

Tags: javascript, http, vue.js, webpack, keycloak

I have a VueJS frontend that uses Keycloak for authentication, further I have Webpack bundling my code. When the application initially loads and the user is not authenticated he gets redirected to the keycloak page.

At this point he  gets the error 
`The resource from “https://auth.xyz.com/auth/...” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)`, because the browser tries to load my bundled .js files and therefore accepts only `type=text/javascript`. 
But because of the redirect he gets served the login page with `type=text/html`.

The only option to Log-In is therefore accessing the login page directly, logging in, then come back to my application that gets properly loaded once he is authenticated.

Im new to webpack, how can I solve this issue? Is there a way to tell webpack that when trying to access my applications javascript it should also accept html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by making the index public and guarding the frontend with keycloak.